# How to assign a value to a char* using hex notation?

Tags: c

I usually use pointers in the following manner

```
    char *ptr = malloc( sizeof(char) * 100 );
    memset( ptr, 0, 100 ) ;
    strncpy( ptr, "cat" , 100 - 1 );
```

But this time instead of using "cat", I want to use it ASCII equivalent in hex.

> cat = 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x00

I tried

```
    strncpy( ptr, "0x630x61" , 100 - 1 );
```

But it fails as expected.

What is the correct syntax?

Do I need to put a 0x00 too? For a moment lets forget about `memset`, now do I need to put a 0x00? Because in "cat" notation, a null is automatically placed.

Regards

Comment: What's the actual use for this? This is mid-interest and mid-this-could-help-drive-a-better-answer...

Comment: Is this related to some UNICODE character? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Romain This question keeps getting asked (but is difficult to search for) - I suspect a  deep misunderstanding by the questioner

Comment: Q. Why would you want to do this? A- I need to make some char* with hexa codes in it to communicate with a device. Those hexa combinations are actually commands for that device. That's why I was looking for the syntax.

Comment: @andrew-dufresne: You probably need a buffer i.e. an array of `unsigned char`. Any particular reason you are using a string and forcing the hex representations on? The internal representation of the string's member won't change depending on whether you input a `\x63` or a `c`.

Comment: @andrew-dufresne Also, in English, it's "hex" or "hexadecimal", not "hexa".

Comment: @dirkgently: I don't have any specific reason for that.I guess its just a matter of style.

Comment: @andrew-dufresne: Good style is usually about readable code. Are you passing passwords and need a minimum effort way of hiding them?

Comment: @dirkgently: No its not the passwords. These are some commands to a device attached through serial port. Commands mentioned in their manual involve such hex values which are not present in keyboards. That's why I have to use hex notation. As for using an array of unsigned char or a char*, these days I am trying to use pointers as much as possible to get a grip on them :-)

Comment: @andrew-dufresne: Then you surely don't need a null-terminated C-string -- the source of my confusion. As for the signedness, I'll leave that your documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\xXX` is the syntax for inserting characters in hex format. so yours would be:

```
strncpy( ptr, "\x63\x61\x74", 100 - 1);
```

You don't need to put in a `\x00` since having quotes automatically null-delimits the string.

Answer (score 8):

Note, you only need \ inside the " " string

```
char cat[4];
cat[0] = 0x63;
cat[1] = 0x61;
cat[2] = 0x74;
car[3] = 0x00;

char cat[] = "\x63\x61\x74"; // note the \0 is added for you

char cat[] = { 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x00 };
```

Are all the same

Comment: I like the way you've shown three options, but "\0x63\0x61\0x74" is wrong. It creates an array containing the characters `0, 'x', '6', '3', 0, ...`. That's zero-length when used as a nul-terminated string.

Comment: Although the resulting executable will have the same _behavior_ these are **not** all the same: 0x63 is an `int` literal that will be converted to a `char`. Some compilers will issue a 'truncation' warning for this. `char cat[] = { '\x63', '\x61', '\x74', '\x00' };` will be the same as `char cat[] = "\x63\x61\x74";` and not generate a compiler warning.

Comment: Beware ! ``cat[0] = 0xAA`` will give you an overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' and ``cat[] = { 0xAA }`` simply won't work you'll get an error of narrowing conversion. Hence you should remove the "Are all the same" it ain't. Check : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1809f688901d0434

Answer (score 2):

```
strncpy( ptr, "\x63\x61" , 100 - 1 );
```

`0x63` is an integer hexadecimal literal; The C compiler parses it as such within code. But within a string it is interpreted as a sequence of characters `0,x,6,3`.
The literal for the `char` with value 63 hex. is `'\x63'`, and within strings you must use this notation.
`"c\x63"` is the literal for a *zero-terminated* string, irrespective of the characters within the quotes (or of the notation by which you denote them), so no, you don't need to append a trailing zero manually.